# How to get current and next value in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame like this:

```
index    twp        lat     lng
0   ABINGTON    40.112603   -75.120223
1   AMBLER  40.157847   -75.220640
2   BERKS COUNTY    40.284542   -75.558035
3   BRIDGEPORT  40.104064   -75.343394
```

I want to get first value and second value then do something and then continue this loop, my process will be like this: (Index number )

to get values in index:

```
(0,1)
(0,2)
(0,3)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)
```

I done with irow() like this:

```
for i in range(0,distance.shape[0]):
    last = distance.irow(i)
     for j in range(i, distance.shape[0]):
        print(last[0])
        nex=distance.irow(j)
        print(nex[0])
```

But irow() is deprecated and I want to do with iloc or something comfortable with python 3.

Also, code above elements repeated with self I want do like  example as I mentioned (index) above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iloc` will return the two rows if you passed them as a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

for i,j in combinations(distance.index, 2):
    distance[[i,j]]  # and do stuff with the 2 rows returned
```